# How to hide element in page according to another page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have three `ContentPage` in Xamarin application.

When application started, all three pages are reachable with swiping. There is no navigation between them.

In first page I have two `RadioButton` and two text areas. According to `RadioButton` selection I can hide or unhide one of text areas but I need to hide or unhide an element in second page.

How can I do this? How can I access elements of second page and hide one of them?

Comment: how are these pages related?  Does Page1 navigate to Page2, or are they both already active, or what?

Comment: When the application started, all pages are active, with swiping you can reach all of them.

Comment: use MessagingCenter to pass messages between them

Comment: Could you please check what's happening in your MainPage? (like tabbed page or other interesting stuff). Options: 1. Pass a value through navigation or switching views. 2. Create a property in App.xaml.cs and share it between views. 3. Use [message center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) (4. Save to database and fetch, not recommended)

Comment: @Jason, thanks for your answer. I Used the message center and with it, I could hide/unhide items on page 2.

Comment: @İlkayGunel please post a solution if you have found an acceptable answer to help others